# AngularJS ng-value and ng-model do not work together

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-value

I was trying to give a value to textfield using ngvalue and textarea has that value but it when I submit it, it recognized as textarea is empty.

```
 <textarea  ng-value="main.record.basic_info.application_letter"
            class="form-control" 
            ng-model="main.record.apply_job.cover_letter" 
            name="name" rows="15" cols="80" style="resize: none">
 </textarea>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to the set the value? On the textbox or the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use these directives together

"It can also be used to achieve one-way binding of a given expression to an input element such as an input[text] or a textarea, **when that element does not use ngModel**."

You should set this value in your controller rather than use ng-value.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that `ng-value` should not be used when doing **two-way** binding with `ng-model`.

From the Docs:

> ## ngValue
>
> Binds the given expression to the value of the element.
>
> It can also be used to achieve **one-way** binding of a given expression to an input element such as an `input[text]` or a `textarea`, **when that element does not use** `ngModel`.
>
> — [AngularJS `ng-value` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Instead, initialize the value from the controller:

```
<textarea  ̶n̶g̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶m̶a̶i̶n̶.̶r̶e̶c̶o̶r̶d̶.̶b̶a̶s̶i̶c̶_̶i̶n̶f̶o̶.̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶_̶l̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶"̶
           class="form-control" 
           ng-model="main.record.name" 
           name="name" rows="15" cols="80" style="resize: none">
</textarea>
```

```js
$scope.main.record.name = $scope.main.record.basic_info.application_letter;
```